# Is the default constructor created if I provide another one?

Tags: plsql, constructor

I haven't found anything about this.
In PL/SQL, if I provide a constructor for an object, the default one will still be created, or it's like in C++ or Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the default constructor is still there. Incidently, if you create another constructor with the same name and arguments you'll get an error `PLS-307: too many declarations of ...` when you try to use it.